# Calling the extraction overloader produces error undefined reference to `operator>>

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a class called "Dollars" to change a float to a money format. but When I try to use the dollars class I am getting an error. Dollars class has and overloaded extraction operator:

```
istream & operator >> (istream & in, Dollars & rhs)
{
   // initially zero                                                                        
   rhs.cents = 0;
   if (in.fail())
      return in;

   // skip leading spaces and dollar signs;                                                 
   while (isspace(in.peek()) || in.peek() == '$')
      in.get();

   // is the next character a negative?                                                     
   bool negative = false;
   while ('-' == in.peek() || '(' == in.peek())
   {
      negative = true;
      in.get();
   }

   // consume digits, assuming they are dollars                                             
   while (isdigit(in.peek()))
      rhs.cents = rhs.cents * 10 + (in.get() - '0');

   // everything up to here was dollars so multiply by 100                                  
   rhs.cents *= 100;

   // did we get a decimal                                                                  
   if ('.' == in.peek())
   {
      // consume the decimal                                                                
      in.get();

      // next digit is in the 10cent place if it exists                                     
      if (isdigit(in.peek()))
         rhs.cents += (in.get() - '0') * 10;
      // the final digit is the 1cent place if it exists                                    
      if (isdigit(in.peek()))
         rhs.cents += (in.get() - '0');
   }

   // take care of the negative stuff                                                       
   rhs.cents *= (negative ? -1 : 1);

   // see if there is a trailing )                                                          
   if (')' == in.peek())
      in.get();

   return in;
}
```

Here is where i try to use it:

```
Dollars dollar;

cout << "Float to convert to Dollars: ";
cin >> dollars;
```

then I just get this error when I compile:

undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, Dollars&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The code that "uses" the operator is incomplete.  (1)  No evidence that the class definition or a declaration of the `operator>>()` are visible to the compiler at the point of use.  Both are essential. (2) The code that "uses" the operator is not in a function, so is not compilable.   (3)   If the definition of the `operator>>()` and the function using it are in separate source files, then information about how you build (compile and link) is relevant to answering the question.   You have provided none of the information needed to allow others to help.  Read up on providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You wrote `operator <<` but you're attempting to call `operator >>`

Comment: sorry, the class has both I copied the right operator >> now

Comment: Are you compiling and linking the file that contains the function definitions?